# Jquery Click in li

Tags: jquery

I have my html set up like this:

```
<li>
    Header
    <button>Edit</button>
</li>
```

And I was wondering if there is a way so that you can click on the li and have one action happen and click on the button and have another action happen. Right now if I have a jquery click element on the li it gets fired when you hit the button to. Is there a way to make this separate without changing the html structure?

Comment: Show us the JQuery code you are using because it must be wrong to trigger on both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `event target` also.

```
$('li').click(function(event) {
      var $tgt=$(event.target);
       if( $tgt.is('button') ){
          alert('button clicked');
       }else{
          alert('li clicked');
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

inside the button click event handler use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) - this will stop the event from bubbling up to the `li`

```
button.click(function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the handler for the button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        alert('li clicked');
    });

    $('button').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert('button clicked');
    });
});​
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JFcj/)